# How to pyinstall a python file to run without terminal (Mac)

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, background-process

I have created a file-sorting python script, and I would like it to run in the background. Right now, it opens up the terminal (I'm on mac) every time it runs, and I don't like that. I made it so it runs every time the computer is booted up. How can I make it windowless/ a background process using pyinstaller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2.7//library/os.html#os.system). Something like this:

```py
import os
os.system("pyinstaller <config> <filename>")
```

To make it run in the background, you could run it with `pythonw`. If you want your script to run continuously, you could use the python module [sched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html) to schedule your script.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I want the compiled python script to run as a background process.

Comment: @Serket -- I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command and make an .exe file of your .py file,

```
pyinstaller -w filename.py
```

This command make an .exe file which will execute your script without popping any console. Means it will execute in background. For executing you script on boot up set [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29338066/mac-osx-execute-a-python-script-at-startup)